# Product key Registration - Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, copy-protection

I am trying to make a product key registrar for my program. I want the product keys in a database or a dictionary type thing where I can make new keys everyday without putting them into the program, and redistrubate them everytime. I'm not sure where to get started, so if anyone has any ideas please post them

thanks,

kevin

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Advanced Installer](http://advancedinstaller.com). They have a licensing system built right in.

Its a bit costly, but it will save you money in the long run. Of course, you could try to make your own. Self-contained registration is a bit more challenging to secure than one that checks a database.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Shareware Starter Kit (free) from Microsoft.

http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2005/07/10/437293.aspx

Comment: I've not used it, but there is a "VB Download" link on the page I posted.

Comment: Yea when I download it from microsoft, it tells me to convert to 2008. and then when I debug it gives me a ton of errors...

Comment: Works great.  Saw this at a MS event a while back, very solid.

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple to begin with. If you need more complexity, or tougher security, then do that after you've got your basic framework developed.

First step. Look at some simple encryption algorithms like the Tiny Encryption Algorithm. Get comfortable with encrypting and decrypting a file using a single key.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm

Next step. You will need lots of keys, a database to store them and some kind of customer id to associate with them. To begin with, lets assume that the customer id is a 6 digit number starting at 100000, the key is 128 bits in hex format, and the database is a simple text file. At this point, you should have no problems making a program to generate a batch of keys for the next 100 customers.

Third step. Now you have a database, so set up some scripts or an application so that you can encrypt a specific file, producing multiple copies, one for each customer ID, encrypted with their key.

Fourth step, write a short simple app that takes a file, decrypts it with a key, then loads and runs the resulting executable file. After the app terminates, delete the decrypted file.

Now the little app that decrypts and runs has to somehow be produced in numerous versions, one for each customer with their key in place. Best way to do that is to generate a random number the same size as the key, and place it as a constant in the code. Then compile it. At this point a tool like grep can find where it is in the executable. Write another small app to read in the decryptor app replace the tag with a real key, and write out a version of the decryptor that you will distribute with the matching decrypted application.

After this, you might want to look at better decryption algorithms than TEA, but don't use something too strong that would run afoul of export laws.

Note that none of this will prevent determined thieves, but it should ward of casual ones and you will learn a lot. Better security can be had with an application that stores critical parts of itself on an encrypted USB key so that there is never a decrypted copy on the hard drive. And remember, any time you think that you have figured out a way to improve the encryption or code protection, you are very likely to be wrong. Much greater minds than ours, have spent their entire lives studying encryption and the general rule is that when you deviate a bit from the accepted algorithms and usages, you end up reducing, not increasing, the security.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling your own Registration and protection program is incredibly difficult, and usually very easy to break.  Try looking at some of the inexpensive commercial products that already do this, [intellilock](http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm) is cheap and I have found to be well featured (if not well supported by the company that produces it, well supported by the community).

Comment: Are there any that are free and aren't demos? I love how Intellilock works but I just don't like how its a demo and costs 129 bucks.. They have something similar like that called Aquatic Prime for the mac thats free.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a central repository of valid codes, users of your software would need an Internet connection to communicate with this repository to determine if their entered license code is valid. This scheme may also have scalability issues.

One commonly used alternative method is to generate codes from bye data satisfying some specific mathematical relation, and then validate the code to see if the relations hold.

One very powerful algorithm based on above concept is the cryptographic RSA algorithm.

If you can use a ready-made licensing system based on RSA, check out [CryptoLicensing](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm).